# Get PFUser reference objects

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have a subclass of PFUser with additional fields:

```
class User: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var myLists:       [BuyList]
    @NSManaged var receivedlists: [BuyList]
    @NSManaged var users:         [User]

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }    
}
```

BuyList is subclass of PFObject.

I create BuyList object, make some horribly things with it and append to the User.myLists. After that I call:

```
User.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
```

In Parse dashboard I have this value in 'myLists' field:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"BuyList","objectId":"D5sGbsEhio"}]
```

But on device object is:

```
<BuyList: 0x7bab9b80, objectId: D5sGbsEhio, localId: (null)> {
//Empty body here
}
```

**How I can receive User object and it's property's?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to load user before HomeScreen opened, so I replaced open method with:

```
private func openHomeScreen() {            
        self.loadList(0) { () -> Void in
            Utils.setRootController("HomeController")
        }            
    }

private func loadList(var index: Int, completition: () -> Void ) {
        User.currentUser()!.myLists[index].fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            index++
            if index == User.currentUser()!.myLists.count {
                completition()
            } else {
                self.loadList(index, completition: completition)
            }                
        }
    }
```